# php regex preg_match allow only certain keywords

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying use preg_match in an IF statement and return false if a string contains some templated functions not allowed.

Here are some example templated functions allowed:

```
{function="nl2br($value.field_30)"}
{function="substr($value.field_30,0,250)"}
{function="addslashes($listing.photo.image_title)"}
{function="urlencode($listing.link)"}
{function="AdZone(1)"}
```

These are mixed in with html etc.

Now I'd like this preg_match statement to return true if regex matches the code format but didn't contain one of the allowed function keywords:

```
if (preg_match('(({function=)(.+?)(nl2br|substr|addslashes|urlencode|AdZone)(.+?)\})',$string)) {
    // found a function not allowed
} else {
    // string contains only allowed functions or doesn't contain functions at all
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Not sure if regular expressions are the best tool. Perhaps they could be combined with an old school old tokenizer and parser :-? The question is nice, though, no matter the potential risks of the feature :)

Comment: I was going to do that, but to keep the code clean I thought I'd ask here first for a simple if statement solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're trying here, but if I were to make a regexp that matched a list of words (or function names as the case may be), I'd do somthing like

```
// add/remove allowed stuff here
$allowed = array( 'nl2br', 'substr', 'addslashes' );

// make the array into a branching pattern
$allowed_pattern = implode('|', $allowed);

// the entire regexp (a little stricter than yours)    
$pattern = "/\{function=\"($allowed_pattern)\((.*?)\)\"\}/";

if( preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches) ) {
    # string DOES contain an allowed function
    # The $matches things is optional, but nice. $matches[1] will be the function name, and
    # $matches[2] will be the arguments string. Of course, you could just do a
    # preg_replace_callback() on everything instead using the same pattern...
} else {
    # No allowed functions found
}
```

The `$allowed` array makes it easier to add/remove allowed function names, and the regexp is stricter about the curly brackets, quotes and general syntax, which is probably a good idea.

But first of all, flip the if..else branches, or use a `!`. `preg_match` is meant for, well, matching stuff in the string, not for matching stuff that isn't in there. So you can't really get it to return `true` for something that *isn't* there

Still, as Álvaro mentioned, regexps probably aren't the best way to go about this, and it is pretty risky to have functions exposed like that, no matter the rest of the code. If you just needed to match words it should work fine, but since it's function calls with arbitrary arguments... well. I can't really recommend it :)

Edit: First time around, I used `preg_quote` on the imploded string, but that of course just escapes the pipe characters, and then the pattern won't work. So skip `preg_quote`, but then just be sure that function names don't contain anything that might mess up the final pattern (e.g. run each function name through `preg_quote` *before* imploding the array)